iPad app for handwriting with Apple pencil including a button on-screen to quickly erase content
I discovered that I recall more, for instance, using Anki, by writing with the Apple Pencil instead of using a keyboard. However, it's a bit tedious to use GoodNotes, write something, and then having to navigate the menu to clear the screen.
Therefore, I wonder if there is an application that allows you to clear everything you draw quickly with an on-screen button, without needing to navigate through a menu.
I have tried with GoodNotes but you need to open a menu. OneNote doesn't have this option. 

Have you looked at OneNote for Mac (free) or Apple’s Freeform product?  I think either of these will be a hit with the patrol?

Thank you for your comment. I will include the apps that I have tried. I think OneNote does not have a always on-screen button to erase all content on a page.

I don’t believe it does, but the ability to “drag-to-select” is really powerfull…

@Allan, thanks! how can I find that option? I used to be a daily OneNote user, but now I cannot do what you mentioned.
